# RVM - Error when try to install RVM in CentOS 6.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I'm with the following problem:

I'm trying to install RVM in the CenteOS 6.8 in the company that I work. When I try to install it on my local machine, everything goes ok. However, when I try to do the same in a CenteOS 6.8 server machine to create the test environment, to the Quality Analyst to test, the curl command didn't work.

Here is how I tried to install it

```
$ gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB

gpg: directory `/root/.gnupg' created
gpg: new configuration file `/root/.gnupg/gpg.conf' created
gpg: WARNING: options in `/root/.gnupg/gpg.conf' are not yet active during this run
gpg: keyring `/root/.gnupg/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/root/.gnupg/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key D39DC0E3 from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
gpg: requesting key 39499BDB from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
gpg: /root/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key D39DC0E3: public key "Michal Papis (RVM signing) <mpapis@gmail.com>" imported
gpg: key 39499BDB: public key "Piotr Kuczynski <piotr.kuczynski@gmail.com>" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 2
gpg:               imported: 2  (RSA: 2)
```

After that, I tried to install RVM with curl like that:

```
$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

After a while, I got:

```
$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable


curl: (35) SSL connect error
```

I had tried tons of option that I found here in the StackOverflow and in the Google but until now, I didn't succeed

Could someone help me, please?

---

@widjajayd, thanks for the help. I tried to do the sequence bellow, but it stopped in the curl command again.

```
yum install git 
git config --global user.name "your name "
git config --global user.email "your email "
cd ~/.ssh
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C “your email”
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s
```

The 'cd ~/.ssh' did not work because it does not exist. So, I created it and inside of it, I run ''ssh-keygen -t rsa -C “your email”.

In the end, I executed the command curl command and I got:

```
$ curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
194   194  194   194    0     0    222      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1405
curl: (35) SSL connect error
```

I had used this command before I attempted this last curl command. However, the result was the same as above.

Comment: the key is when you run ssh-keygen -t rsa -C abcde@gmail.com, it will create 2 files id_rsa and id_rsa.pub, please check whether this file created / not

Comment: I also read some comments , if you using old curl try to updating curl and nss, here is some tip https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=57349

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to install it is to do its offline installation.

Just follow the steps in the RVM website:

https://rvm.io/rvm/offline

It will explain how to download the RVM in a different way, plus how to install it with this downloaded file.

Answer (score 0):

probably in you local machine you already set ssl correctly but in your production you not set ssl,

below some step by step for you to double check in centos

```
yum install git 
git config --global user.name "your name "
git config --global user.email "your email "
cd ~/.ssh
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C “your email”
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s
```

To start using RVM you need to run source

```
source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
test rvm -v
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. Above with my doubt. I put the result about your suggestions. Could you check, please? The problem persists yet.